# sql server multi case where clause

Tags: sql-server

I want to retrieve rows where DaysVisted are between two values, e.g if @days is 90 then fetch records which has DaysVisited between 90 and 60, if @days is 60 then fetch records which has DaysVisited between 60 and 30.

Following query is not giving me correct records:

```
declare @days int
set @days = 60
select * from table where
DaysVisited >=
CASE                
   when  (@days = 90) then 
   when  (@days = 60) then @days       
   when  (@days = 0) then 0
END
```

I want like this:

```
declare @days int
set @days = 60
select * from table where

CASE                
   when  (@days = 90) then DaysVisited >= 90 and DaysVisited <= 60 
   when  (@days = 60) then DaysVisited >= 60 and DaysVisited <= 30 
   when  (@days = 0) then 0
END
```

Comment: So it's just always the days and days - 30?

Comment: not always, days can be zero also, these can change

Comment: Just add a second variable and put the second limit there?

Comment: How i can achieve that? Please give me sample query. I am not getting your point.

Comment: "where DaysVisited >=@days and DaysVisited <=@days2"

Comment: It isn't clear what the desired results are when `@days = 0`?

Comment: when days = 0 then show all records.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic would not be possible, a column cannot be below 60 and above 90 at the same time. Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @days int = 60

SELECT * 
FROM 
  yourtable
WHERE
  DaysVisited between 
    case when @days < 30 then 0 else @days-30 end and @days
```

Comment: if user select 90 then i want to get rows having DaysVisited more than 90, if user select 60 then between 60 and 90, if zero then all records.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @days int = 60;
DECLARE @MaxDay INT; 
SELECT @MaxDay = MAX(DaysVisited) FROM YourTable;
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DaysVisited BETWEEN @days AND 
      CASE 
          WHEN @days=60 THEN 90
          ELSE @MaxDay
       END
```